# Change sorting direction of Isotope plugin in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope for a home page menu layout.
This is my current layout: cellsByColumn and the settings for it follows:

cellsByColumn : {
    columnWidth : 50,
    rowHeight : 50
  }

This works well, except for one problem. The sorting is top to bottom. Is there any way to make the sorting left to right?

Best regards,

Tony.

Comment: Have you read through the docs: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html ?

Comment: @Honneykeepa yes, and found the solution as well. I just have to use cellsByRow. Some how didn't see that earlier. Thank you.